# necesito una explicación para el bucle for en este caso

Tags: java, bucle-for

recien estoy aprendiendo a programar ,eh entiendo un poco como es la estructura
pero no entiendo exactamente como lo toma java esta expresion si es que lo toma tal cual se estuviera inicializando o no:

```
int j=2;
    for ( ;j < 5;j++)
        System.out.println("hola mundo");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu codigo es valido, por que al campo de inicializacion, la sentencia `for` solamente entra 1 sola vez hasta que termina el ciclo.

```
int j=2;
    for ( ;j < 5;j++)
        System.out.println("hola mundo");
```

por lo que si pondrias

```
int j;
    for (j=2 ;j < 5;j++)
        System.out.println("hola mundo");
```

o pondrias:

```
   for ( int j=2; j < 5;j++)
        System.out.println("hola mundo");
```

serian equivalentes.

Comment: La diferencia entre los dos primeros casos y el tercero es que en los dos primeros casos la variable `j` sería del ambito local del metodo que contenga el `for`, mientras que en la tercera la valiable `j` solo es del ambito del `for`